# jQuery .button() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery .button() on a checkbox, but i can't understand why this is'not working.

this is the javascript code:

```
$('#login_checkbox').button();
```

and this is the html code:

```
<input id="login_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="login_remember"/><label>Remember me</label>
```

I'm doing everything exacly as shown here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Comment: Your code looks fine, did you install jQuery UI along with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the for attribute or it won't know which label to use:

```
<label for="login_checkbox">Remember me</label>
```

Comment: Thank you Hogan! You save me an headache! I hate those kinds of mistakes!

Comment: @Silvio accept his answer to make me feel a little less cheap for guessing at something that wasn't your actual problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is that code running in a "ready" handler, or just naked in a `<script>` block in the head of your page?

In other words, are you sure that the element exists at the time the Javascript code runs?  That's a really easy mistake to make, especially when throwing together little proofs-of-concept.

Comment: The JS code is inserted along with other working lines: $(function()
        {
            $('#tac').hide();
            $('#username_error').hide();
            $('#password_error').hide();
            $('#email_error').hide();
            $('#login_checkbox').button();
            $('#login_choice_container').buttonset();
        }); .The only thing not working is $('#login_checkbox').button(); :S